# docker ADD --chown bug or feature?

Tags: docker, ownership

I am having a problem adding a file to an image and setting ownership via `--chown` flag. Specifically, here is a dockerfile adding a simple text file:

```
FROM fedora:24

ARG user_name=slave
ARG user_uid=1000
ARG user_home=/home/$user_name/

RUN useradd -l -u ${user_uid} -ms /bin/bash $user_name

WORKDIR ${user_home}
USER ${user_name}
ADD --chown=1397765041:1397765041 test.txt ./
CMD ls -l
```

This results in expected ownership of `text.txt` as can be seen:

```
$ docker run --rm -it bm/tmp:latest
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 some_user 1397765041 6 Oct 21 20:00 test.txt
```

Cool. Now if I change `test.txt` to a tar file (for example boost_1_57_0.tar.bz2), and rebuild, this is what I get:

```
$ docker run --rm -it bm/tmp:latest
total 4
drwx------ 8 501 root 4096 Oct 31  2014 boost_1_57_0
```

Here is how I am building (probably doesn't matter tho):

```
docker build -t bm/tmp --build-arg user_name=some_user --build-arg user_uid=1397765041 .
```

As we can see, ownership is NOT as expected in this case. It seems the behavior of `--chown` differs from the two cases shown above. I know that `ADD` automatically extracts tars. I don't know how the ownership is being set in the case where the file is a tar file. Anyone?

Comment: As you may know adding a `RUN` command just to set ownership will create a new (relatively large) layer just for performing that command. Which is fine. But given that the `ADD` command has a `--chown` flag, one would expect that flag to work with `ADD` regardless of the input type. 

For now I am extracting the tar file outside of docker, then I am using a docker `COPY` with the `--chown` flag.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, `ADD --chown` only works for regular files. `ADD` with a tarball uses the ownership and permissions listed inside in tarball.

Workarounds:

- Run `tar` yourself with `--owner`/`--owner-map`/`--group`/`--group-map`.
- `chown -R` after the `ADD`.